# Boolean algebra, simplification

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to simplify the following expression:
$$a'·b·(a'+c)+a·b'·(b'+ c)$$

The problem is that when I try it, I end up with a $0$ multiplying the expression, so everything becomes cero. I get confused with the parentheses in the addition, and I've asked in some other forums but everyone gets different answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Given expression, $$ a' \cdot b( a' + c) + a \cdot b' \cdot ( b' + c) $$ $$ = a' \cdot b \cdot a' + a' \cdot b \cdot c + a \cdot b' \cdot b' + a \cdot b' \cdot c$$  $$ = a' \cdot b + a \cdot b' + a' \cdot b \cdot c + a \cdot b' \cdot c $$ $$ ( a' \cdot b + a \cdot b')\cdot ( c + 1) =   a' \cdot b + a \cdot b' $$

It can be verified from [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(not%20a)%20and%20b%20and%20(%20(not%20a)%20or%20c)%20or%20a%20and%20(%20not%20b)%20and%20(%20(not%20b)%20or%20c)) .